# What does HRESULT 0x80040012 (OLE_E_NOSTORAGE) mean?

Tags: c#, c++, com

My Google-Fu has obediently told me that the following error

```
Not able to perform the operation because object is not given storage yet (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040012 (OLE_E_NOSTORAGE))
```

which is being thrown from a C++ function called in a C# project is, in fact, an error which is related to OLE.  But I can't find much more beyond that - what might cause such an error, or what functions would return it.

More baffling is the fact that although I know the code I'm using has spat out this error before, I personally haven't been able to reproduce it.  It's coming from a pair of unit tests, so I doubt that I'm missing some vital step to reproduce the error, unless it's due to some arcane machine configuration.  Can anyone help me understand where it might be coming from?

Comment: Facility code 4 (the fifth hex digit from the right), aka `FACILITY_ITF`, is reserved for interface-specific, user-defined error codes. It's possible that the error you receive just happens to match the numeric value of `OLE_E_NOSTORAGE` by accident, sending you on a wild goose chase.